# Detect specific app.state change in Ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

Is there any method to detect Particular states change only like in my case 
I want to run a function only if we go from app.state 1 to app.state 2.
*controller.js*

```
 if(app.state1 to app.state2) {
    $scope.run();
    }
```

I have searched too but found nothing related to this. 
Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic routes used angular ui-router therefore event callbacks are used in the same way:

[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Where appropriate:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(toState.name == 'stateA' && fromState.name == 'stateB') {
        // run your code
        $scope.run();
    }
});
```

**(UPDATE)**

if you need to ask for more than one state:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    var states = ['stateB', 'stateC', 'stateD'];

    if(toState.name == 'stateA' && states.indexOf(fromState.name) > -1) {
        // run your code
        $scope.run();
    }
});
```

Comment: one more question. Can we add multiple *fromState.name* ?

Comment: You're welcome, The fromState will always bring only the current state to which the router will go. If you want to ask for more than one state, you can use a single javascript code: `var states = ['stateB', 'stateC', 'stateD']; if(states.indexOf(fromState.name) > -1){ ... }`

Comment: I am unable to do it right I think. Can you provide me full code as I can't understand what to write inside **{}**.

Comment: thank you so much.I think you are much aware of ionic so can you check this issue too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005207/ionic-hide-nav-bar-not-the-buttons

Comment: it is creating an error. I have set **hide-nav-bar="true"** on "stateB" then on coming back from stateB to stateA it shows my nav-bar. I have used a function to refresh a page inplace of *$scope.run() here.

Comment: @Atula I also answered your other question